# Can you apply for UK citizenship while there on a tourist visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, uk-citizenship

My son (7yo) has a right to British citizenship, but we need to be in the UK in the autumn/winter and I'm worried about applying and it not coming through in time. Can you apply for a visa and citizenship in parallel? Or could we just do visa and then apply for his citizenship when we get there? Or any other things I haven't though of?

ETA: Sorry, more information. So my son is Bolivian, adopted here as a national adoption, therefore he has to apply for citizenship. My elder son is the same situation, and his UK citizenship came through in three months with no issues at all - so I'm not really worried about him getting it, however my elder son has a surgery in the UK in November/December time and I'm concerned about the younger's citizenship not coming through in time. Hope that answers any questions!

Comment: Most people HAVE British citizenship but no passport, not a "right to" British citizenship. Could you tell us why you think he has a "right to" British citizenship but not actually British citizenship?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing a Passport for Citizenship? They are very different things!

Comment: What is the basis of your son's claim to British citizenship?  What application are you planning to submit?  He might be eligible to become a British citizen by registration or he might already be a British citizen.  You haven't given enough information for us to know which it is, but the answer will be very different for each possibility.

Comment: Sorry, more information. So my son is Bolivian, adopted here as a national adoption, therefore he has to apply for citizenship. My elder son is the same situation, and his UK citizenship came through in three months with no issues at all - so I'm not really worried about him getting it, however my elder son has a surgery in the UK in November/December time and I'm concerned about the younger's citizenship not coming through in time. Hope that answers any questions!